# I was refused a UK visa

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens, proof-of-ties

Q1: Please what can I do next?
Q2: What does it means for me in future and when I re-apply again?
Q3: Is it good idea to reapply back in 1 month time?

[image]

Comment: This is probably the worst refusal I’ve ever seen on TSE. It indicates that you do not meet any of the eligibility criteria and did not provide any relevant supporting documents. There’s no point re-applying. Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: @Traveller Suppose the OP could file a new application with proper documentation (Letter from University of Ulster identifying the paperwork and explaining why it must be collected in person, letter from a university in Nigeria showing the OP is a current student, but permitted to be absent for the trip to the UK, bank statements showing sufficient excess of income over expenses to justify the trip...). Would it be worth reapplying?

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Maybe, if the OP can file a strong application. The premise of collecting paperwork seems weak but I suppose it could depend on what that paperwork is and why the OP can’t just arrange for it to be posted to them.

Comment: In the era of online and international postage, what is the reason to fly from Nigeria to the UK to collect some *paper* document? This application smells a lot.

Comment: I made mistakes, please what can I do next?

Comment: Read the linked question and answer. Fully document evidence that you have strong ties to your home country and sufficient funds to afford a 22 day trip to the UK. In addition, given the unusual situation, you need a letter from the University of Ulster explaining why you need to collect the paperwork in person. When I applied to a US PhD program all the paperwork related to my London University bachelor's and master's degrees was done through e-mail to the two colleges involved. That is normal. Needing to collect paperwork in person is not, and needs documentation.

Answer (score 3):

> To go to my university to get some document which will be of help in the future

Really? Is that the best you came up with in a visa application? I'm sorry to be blunt but you just wasted your hard earned money. That was never going to get approved that way.

Successful applicants spend a great deal of time or attention on applications to make a strong case. Those vague statements do not get visas.

Please consider reapplying only when there is a more convincing reason.

Even a non-visa national can not be so casual in a landing interview and expect leave to be granted, let alone a visa application.

Comment: I have tried to get a letter from my university but the are not responding back. Please what can I do next?

Comment: @Zukqi Why do you think you have to go to collect the paperwork in person? Can you address all the other deficiencies in your application? Read the linked question and answer to understand what is required and if/how you can meet those requirements. If you can’t get a letter confirming that you must go in person, you have no evidence to support the stated reason for the trip and there is nothing you can do. Don’t even think about re-applying quickly with a different reason - that will just further damage your credibility and lead to another refusal.

Comment: Ok the paperwork was Recommendation or reference letter which I call my school for it previously but the told me that I have to get it from my lectures only and I thought if I am going to visit uk while not go and pick it up my self.